# How to get Grunt-Contrib-Jasmine to execute specs and load dependencies?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

The project is: Backbone + Require + Underscore + Grunt + Grunt-Contrib-Jasmine + Grunt-Lib-PhantomJS

So two serious problems I've been battling. I know that phantomjs is running properly etc. as I get tons of runtime errors if I include my app src files. I've even ordered the deps properly such that Backbone does not barf with `_` not being defined etc.

**1)** When I include my application src, I get the error `can't find variable: define` for all my source files. I've tried putting requirements into `src[]` isntead of `vendor[]` and even tried loading a RequireJSConfig.js that has the deps in it.

**2)** Here's the cruncher: I'm pretty certain I'm pointing at my spec files properly. If I just point to *one test*, it still says `No Specs Executed. Is there a configuration error?` In my case, I just point at my `UserModelUnitTest.js`, which is very simple. It does not execute. I'm going absolutely nuts!

**The Spec (UserModelUnitTest.js):**

```
describe('User Model Unit Tests', function() {
var USER_MODEL,
    USER_CLASS,
    JSON_OBJ;
  beforeEach(function() {
    USER_CLASS = testr('models/user/User', {});
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    USER_MODEL = null;
    USER_CLASS = null;
    JSON_OBJ = null;
  });    
  describe('Given a json object', function() {
    it('should create a valid User', function() {
      JSON_OBJ = {"databaseId": 123456,"loginName": "god","firstName": "Jesus","lastName": "Christ","phone": "666-666-6666","email": "satan@hell.org","isoCountryCode": "US","languageCode": "en","roles" : ["SALES_REP"]};
      USER_MODEL = new USER_CLASS(JSON_OBJ, { parse: true });
      expect(USER_MODEL).not.toBe(null);
    });
    // etc...
  });
})
```

**Here's my dir structure**

```
/project
 - src
     - main
     + test 
        + js
            +unit
                 UserModelUnitTest.js
```

**Here's my Gruntfile / Jasmine config**

```
 jasmine: {
          test:{
              vendor:[
                  'src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/jquery-2.1.0.js',
                  'src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/require-2.1.1.full.js',
                  'src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/underscore-1.5.2.min.js',
                  'src/main/resources/js/lib-clean/backbone-1.1.2.min.js'
              ],
              src : [
                  // these all error like crazy. Can't find variable 'define' etc.
                  // 'src/main/**/*.js',                         
                  // 'src/main/**/**/*.js',
                  //'src/test/RequireJSConfig.js'
              ],
              helpers : [
                  'src/test/js/helpers/dependencyHelper.js',
                  'src/test/js/helpers/errorHelper.js',
                  'src/test/js/helpers/requesetHelper.js',
                  'src/test/lib/testr.js',

                  // jasmine.js + jasmine-html.js etc
                  'src/test/lib/*.js',

                  // stubs
                  'src/test/js/stubs/*.js'
              ],
              specs : [
                  'src/test/js/unit/UserModelUnitTest.js'
              ],
              //specs : 'src/test/js/unit-headless.html',
              timeout : 10000,
              phantomjs : {
                  'ignore-ssl-errors' : true
              }
          }
      },
```

[image: But I do have specs!!!!]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem. You need to define `vendor`, `specs`, `helpers` within the `options` option.

```
jasmine: {
  src: 'path/to/src',
  options: {
    vendor: 'path/to/vendor',
    specs: 'path/to/specs',
    helpers: 'path/to/specs'
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes happen because: you did not created the spec folder and the spec file, also when you create the spec file you need create the test inside or will not run.